# Reading wrong integers in text file

Tags: c, file-io

I need to come up with a program that reads a list of numbers and generate a histogram of values. The numbers are listed line by line in a text file. As such, I thought that using a fscanf would be appropriate because it stops reading upon entering white space characters. But, I'm not sure at all between fgets or fscanf. Another reason why I chose fscanf was because fscanf just assigns the number read into a variable, not an array. I do not need an array, because I just want to examine each number read with the conditions and increment the corresponding counter. Anyway, the code could not work, and in trying to trace what's wrong, I have it print out what number it reads, and I don't know why the numbers read are different from that in the text file. The expected execution trace is :

```
1- 9: XXXX
10-19: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
20-29: XXXXXXXXX
```

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ()
{
    FILE *ptr_file;
    int count [10] = {0}, a = 0;

    ptr_file = fopen("histogram-input.txt", "r"); 

    if ( !ptr_file )
    return 1;

    while ( fgetc(ptr_file) != EOF )
    {
        fscanf (ptr_file, "%d", &a);
        printf("%d\n", a);


            if ( a >=1 && a <= 9 )
            {
                count [0] ++;
            }

            else if ( a >= 10 && a <= 19 )
            {
                count [1] ++;
            }

            else if ( a >= 20 && a <= 29 )
            {
                count [2] ++;
            }

            else if ( a >= 30 && a <= 39 )
            {
                count [3] ++;
            }

            else if ( a >= 40 && a <= 49 )
            {
                count [4] ++;
            }

            else if ( a >= 50 && a <= 59 )
            {
                count [5] ++;
            }

            else if ( a >= 60 && a <= 69 )
            {
                count [6] ++;
            }
            else if ( a >= 70 && a <= 79 )
            {
                count [7] ++;
            }

            else if ( a >= 80 && a <= 89 )
            {
                count [8] ++;
            } 

            else if ( a >= 90 && a <= 99 )
            {
                count [9] ++;
            }


    }

    fclose ( ptr_file );

    for ( int k = 0; k < 10; k++ )
    {
        if ( k == 0 )
        {
            printf("1-9: ");

            for ( int h = 1; h <= count [0]; h++ )
            {
                printf("X");
            }
            printf("\n");
        }

        else
        {
            printf("%d-%d: ", k*10, k*10 + 9 );

            for ( int h = 1; h <= count [k]; h++ )
            {
                printf("X");
            }
            printf("\n");
        }

    }

    return 0;
}
```

My Xs in the histogram output of my program goes on for way too many times.

Here is a tiny part of my execution trace:

```
12
45
95
72
28
7
```

The first numbers in my text file are :

```
1
57
51
31
68
98
6
```

I do not understand why the numbers read are different. Can someone help me out? Thanks!

Comment: This does not answer your question, but you can simplify your if...else chain by dividing by 10.

Comment: What does that mean?

Comment: You can reduce your whole if...else chain to a single line. You should read about integer division. Take a close look at the numbers you compare in the `if` part and the index you are using for the array. Do you see a pattern?

Comment: Is it something like: if ( a/10 == n) count [n]++?

Comment: Question: what is the purpose of the for loop inside the while loop?

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry. I forgot to remove that. I used that when I was using fgets instead of fscanf. I'll edit that now.

Comment: As for your attempt at reducing the code, you are kind of on the right track. However, you don't have a variable named `n`. You also don't need to do a comparison. If `n` has a value and you already know it is the index, there is no need to do `a/10`. Try a few example values of `a` and see what the result of `a/10` is.

Answer (score 1):

You have two problems:

1. Each time the while loop repeats, you do a `fgetc()` which reads a character from the file, then you do `fscanf()` to read an integer. The `fgetc()` interferes with correct results of the `fscanf()`.
2. You have an extra for loop inside the while loop. This essentially counts each number 100 times.

Comment: How does fgetc () interfere with fscanf()?

Comment: Because it reads a character. Remember that a file is just a sequence of characters. Once a character is read, it is no longer available for a subsequent read. `fscanf()` reads a sequence of characters and translates them into whatever data you want. In this case, you want to read the characters `5` and `7` and get the number fifty-seven. However, `fgetc()` reads the `5` and then `fscanf()` only sees the number seven.

Comment: "Remember that a file is just a sequence of characters. Once a character is read, it is no longer available for a subsequent read." --> Disagree, use `unget()` to put 1 character back.